# google sheets api on remote server

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I followed this guide: https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php and have a php file that seems to work through terminal on my mac that can read the sample Google sheet.

My question is how do I get this to work on a remote server where my webpage is located?

The guide seems to simply get me setup with a local test environment but I want to be able to read from a Google sheet on my hosts server. what is my next move?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values) guide.

For example if you want to read from a single range you can use:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheet_id/values/range
```

> -[sheetId](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts) is used frequently in the Sheets API to specify which sheet is being read
>   or updated. In the Sheets UI, you can find the sheetId of the open
>   sheet in the spreadsheet URL, as the value of the gid parameter. The
>   following shows the structure of the URL and where sheetId can be
>   found:
>
> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetId/edit#gid=sheetId`

When I did this ins JS REST call it looked something like this:

```
xhr.open('GET','https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!B3:B71', true);
```

Here, I'm trying to read values from B3 to B71. Read more on [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts) about this.

To do this in PHP, check the [php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client).